# Stored procedure with ADO.NET - String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have an SQL table with the following fields (type in parenthesis)

- id (varchar(255)) primary key
- dateStarted (date)
- dateFirstPayement (date)
- amount (decimal)
- numberPayments (int)
- telNum (varchar(20)) foreign key
- VIN (varchar(255)) foreign key

None of these accept NULL.

I am trying to insert some values from a C# program, here is how I get the values from the WPF form.

**id** 
 `string id = textBox_id.Text;`

**startingDate, firstPaymentDate** 
`DateTime startDate = Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker_startDate1.SelectedDate);`
`DateTime dateFirstP= Convert.ToDateTime(datePicker_firstP.SelectedDate);`

**telNum, NIV** 
`string telNum = comboBox_telNum.SelectedValue.ToString();` 
`string VIN = comboBox_VIM.SelectedValue.ToString();`

**amount, numberPayments** 
`Decimal amount = Convert.ToDecimal(textBox_amount.Text);` 
`int numberPayments = Convert.ToInt32(textBox_numberPayment.Text);`

Here is my C# code to execute the stored procedure that inserts the values :

```
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        builder.DataSource = "D106213";
        builder.InitialCatalog = "ML645";
        builder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

        connection.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString; 
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand newLocation = new SqlCommand("nouvelleLocation", connection);
        newLocation.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        newLocation.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idLocation", id);
        newLocation.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateDebut", startDate);
        newLocation.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datePremierPaiement", dateFirstP);
        newLocation.Parameters.AddWithValue("@montantPremierPaiement", amount);
        newLocation.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombrePaiement", numberPayments);
        newLocation.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numTel", telNum);
        newLocation.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NIV", VIN);

        newLocation.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This is the error that I get when I try to insert the information through my WPF form:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): String or binary data would be truncated
```

The code to connect to the database is fine, as it's working for all my other procedures using the same ConnectionString. I didn't post it all for clarity purposes, but it is wrapper in a try/catch block to handle the exceptions.

What I assume is that the data types in SQL and C# are not equivalent and one of them is causing a problem. I'm certain that the size of the data (ex: strings) is not exceeding the maximum lenght defined in SQL.

Sorry for the messy text formatting, I'm new to using StackOverflow and I didn't get the hang of it yet.

Thank you all very much for your help, and have a nice day.

**EDIT**

It is now fixed. My problem was that in the stored procedure, I inversed/swapped two values (telNum and VIN) so it was trying to insert the VIN value in the telNum column. The telNum only accepted VARCHAR(20) initially, and the VIN was 23 caracters long ..

I almost missed it, I originally changed the data types to VARCHAR(50) for the telNum (and thus I didn't had the error), but then I realized something was wrong when I was getting a foreign key error.

Thank you for your great help, it's extremely appreciated.

Comment: If you are sure that data is not exceeding the maximum length. Then use a profiler to see the call that is sent to database. You are passing datetime to Date field. That can be an issue.

Comment: try adding .Trim() to see if it fixed the problem ?

Comment: and maybe the problem is with your procedure? did you try to execute it at sql server-side with those parameters ?

Comment: I would be suspicious of the values coming out of the comboboxes. Have you examined them in debug mode? It might be worthwhile adding a couple of debug.asserts to verify the length of the retrieved strings.

Comment: As much as you seem certain that none of your strings is too long, SQL is literally telling you "one of your strings is too long". You just need to figure out which one is longer than you think. Have you tried stepping through the code? Profiling the SQL activity?

Comment: @Eshan What do you recommand that I do instead? Change the SQL data type to DateTime too? The sp is working fine in SQL management studio using the same values that are "generated" by the program. The variables containing the results of the comboBoxes are indeed strings and of the proper lenght. =/ There are only three strings, one is 10 char long, the other 1 and the other 20.

Comment: Yes, try that. And preferably pick the call from profiler to see the error.

Comment: Please check Field length in DB table. And you are trying to save string exceed the Field length. Either change the field length or Trim your input string as per Field length.

Comment: Throw a bit of debugging around your strings as a rough test. E.g: `if(id.length > 255) throw new Excpetion("ID is too long: " + id.length);` etc. That will let you know if the input id too large. Or just add a break point and inspect the size of the stings.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is either with the input parameter datatypes to the Stored Procedure (hard to tell without the proc signature being posted) or possibly with the adding of the values to the SqlParameterCollection in C#.

The first thing to check is that the 3 string fields:

- id (varchar(255))
- telNum (varchar(20))
- VIN (varchar(255))

are defined with the same max length between the table and the Stored Procedure. One technical nuance with SQL Server Stored Procedures that is being overlooked is that they silently truncate values. This means that as long as the max lengths (and all of the datatypes, really) match between the table and the input parameters, it is not possible to get a "*String or binary data would be truncated*" error (unless you are manipulating the values after they come into the proc but before the INSERT / UPDATE statement).

If those all match then the problem cannot be the procedure. The next thing to check is the use of the `AddWithValue` method of the SqlParameterCollection.  I recall reading somewhere that it doesn't always work as expected in terms of string lengths. Try changing those 3 fields to straight `Add` calls passing in `new SqlParameter("@idLocation", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255)` where you can specify the exact max length of each field.

Comment: I definatly suggest explicitly creating the SQL Parameters for you string inputs, making sure to give them their expected sizes.

Comment: Thank you, I edited my code and it's working fine now. I don't think it was a problem with `AddWithValue`, but nonetheless I still changed it to avoid any further problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the SQL Profiler to see exactly the data being passed to the stored procedure. Otherwise it's hard to know which variable is exceeding the expected parameter.